# Production crash swift

Tags: ios, swift, crash, production

This is the stack trace we got from Apple.

I tried to debug but I'm unable to reproduce the crash.

What might be the reason?

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: 
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Last Exception Backtrace: 0   CoreFoundation
>     0x184233164 **exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:166) 1
>
>   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x18347c528 objc_exception_throw + 56
>   (objc-exception.mm:521) 2   CoreFoundation                    0x184240628
>   -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 140 (NSObject.m:322) 3   CoreFoundation                 0x184238b10 ___forwarding_** + 1380
>   (NSForwarding.m:3220) 4   CoreFoundation                  0x18411dccc
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92 5   UIKit                          0x18d9f3200 -[UIWebDocumentView setSelectedTextRange:] + 144
>   (UIWebDocumentView.m:5157) 6   UIKit
>     0x18d97fda0 -[UITextSelection commit] + 308 (UITextSelection.m:91) 7 
>   UIKit                             0x18de7334c
>   -[UITextGestureClusterUneditable oneFingerTapInUneditable:] + 1144 (UITextGestureCluster.m:1465) 8   UIKit
>     0x18de8aca4 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget
>   _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 64 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:105) 9   UIKit                             0x18de8f298
>   _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 124 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:1129) 10  UIKit
>     0x18d967a14 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 320
>   (UIGestureRecognizer.m:1168) 11  UIKit
>     0x18d81eb50 -[UIGestureRecognizer
>   _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 732 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:0) 12  UIKit                           0x18de78b08
>   _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1084 (UIGestureEnvironment.m:159) 13  UIKit                             0x18de78678 -[UIGestureEnvironment
>   _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 404 (UIGestureEnvironment.m:1213) 14  UIKit
>     0x18de777d4 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] +
>   276 (UIGestureEnvironment.m:1108) 15  UIKit
>     0x18d81ce5c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3180 (UIWindow.m:2262) 16  UIKit
>     0x18d7ede7c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340 (UIApplication.m:10211)
>   17  UIKit                             0x18e14330c
>   **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2364 (UIEventDispatcher.m:1445) 18  UIKit
>
>     0x18e145898 __handleEventQueueInternal + 4760
>   (UIEventDispatcher.m:1691) 19  UIKit
>
>     0x18e145c00 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5632
>   (UIEventDispatcher.m:1730) 20  UIKit
>
>     0x18e13e7b0 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152
>   (UIEventDispatcher.m:1659) 21  CoreFoundation
>
>     0x1841db77c
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1982) 22  CoreFoundation                 0x1841db6fc
>   __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88 (CFRunLoop.c:2017) 23  CoreFoundation                   0x1841daf84 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2053) 24 
>   CoreFoundation                    0x1841d8b5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
>   (CFRunLoop.c:2920) 25  CoreFoundation                 0x1840f8c58
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245) 26  GraphicsServices
>     0x185fa4f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245) 27  UIKit
>     0x18d8515c4 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3956) 28 
>   APPNAME_PROD                  0x1009129e4 main + 56
>   (AppDelegate.swift:9) 29  libdyld.dylib                   0x183c1856c
>   start + 4

Comment: Some selector it is not able to find, hence crashing check your [UIWebDocumentView setSelectedTextRange:]

Comment: I dont have that UIWebDocumentView in my project.

Comment: have you added any Gesture to any of your view ?

Comment: Yes,my application contains a map view and many other places where gestures are added.

Comment: may be one of your Gesture registered selector is not proper or defined properly, due to that UIKit is not able to handle that. Check all your Gesture selector properly.